# Cant find the specific td in table element to click on using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

So this is the element I'm trying to get to

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="930"><tbody>
 <tr>
   <td height="32"><span style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration:underline; font-size:14px;" onClick="commentsDisplay(9427356)"><b>Display / write / close (0) comment(s) for this video.</b></span> </td>
 </tr> </tbody></table>
```

It has no id, no name, no nothing... and there are multiple table elements in this webpage... how can I get it to be distinct and get `WebDriver` to click on it? I tried use the *partialLinkText*, but it didn't work (kinda expected, since it's not an attribute tag)

here's my java class

```
 // Find the text input element by its name

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("q"));

        // Enter something to search for

        element.sendKeys(searchQ[rnd.nextInt(4)]);

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element

        element.submit();

        //Open random Video

        driver.findElement(By.className("miniature")).click();

        //Open Comments box

        By xpath = By.xpath("//span[contains(@onClick,'commentsDisplay')]/b");
        WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
        myDynamicElement.click();

        // Check the title of the page

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
```

Comment: Have you tried driver.executeScript("commentsDisplay(9427356);","")?

Comment: I met same issue, did you solve it? And How?...:(

Comment: @Fiona my apologies for the late reply, but I ended up going by 'xpath' if you know the element DOM positioning will be static

Answer (score 0):

Try the following **xpath**

```
//span[contains(@onClick,'commentsDisplay')]/b
```

Or **css**

```
span[onClick^='commentsDisplay']>b
```

If that element is taking some time to load uses `explicit` wait along with that:

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//span[contains(@onClick,'commentsDisplay')]/b");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
myDynamicElement.click();
```

Comment: Using the xpath, it says "No such element"

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: My code is very simple, instantiated the webdriver class, opens up the website correctly, searches and navigates properly, but it just can't seem to find this exact element.. I tried all three codes, Don't see any errors in eclipse, but every time I get thrown an exception because it couldn't find element

Comment: Is there any `iframe` present?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any

Comment: I added a stack if that helps

Comment: Where is that failing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting which index of table tag you are trying to click from html, then try below code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[1]/tr/td[contains(@onClick,'commentsDisplay')]")).click();
```

If the tables displayed in the page dynamically, then you need to `Thread.sleep(some time)` for some time (observe approx. how much it takes to load manually) and click on that element.